# getValues and setValues with different ranges

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having a Google script that sets values of specific ranges from sheet B to sheet A on a button press.

The code I have works, but it takes about 40 seconds due to the high amount of getValue/setValue usage I guess.

The code seen below is only a snippet. It goes on like this about four times as shown.

I already have a nice solution for copying values from one large range (say A1:Z30 via loops but I can not figure out a solution for this matter here.

Your support is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
ratenprogrammmain.getRange("E1:E18").setValues(vorlage.getRange("E13:E30").getValues());

ratenprogrammmain.getRange("B2").setValue(vorlage.getRange("B14").getValue());

ratenprogrammmain.getRange("B5").setValue(vorlage.getRange("B17").getValue());

ratenprogrammmain.getRange("A21").setValue(vorlage.getRange("A33").getValue());

ratenprogrammmain.getRange("B25").setValue(vorlage.getRange("B37").getValue());

ratenprogrammmain.getRange("A28:G33").setValues(vorlage.getRange("A40:G45").getValues());

ratenprogrammmain.getRange("H35").setValue(vorlage.getRange("H47").getValue());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Three ideas how to make your code more effiient

- If your sheets are located in the same Spreadsheet you can use the [`copyTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) method for ranges.
- [Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) provides samples how to use **batch operations** to make you code faster and more efficient.
- [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) allows you to use the Sheets API batchUpdate Request [`CopyPasteRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#copypasterequest)

Comment: The copyTo() method has helped me immensely. It is much more resource efficient than setValue() in my case. Thank you very much for your assistance.